# R Markdown Error when knit, code works fine in R

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I have code that runs fine in R Markdown.  It also runs fine in R on its own.  I then installed knitr to be able to access external code chunks and now get the following error.  I have run `update.packages()` and everything is up to date.

```
Error in .Call(C_stri_flatten, str, collapse, na_empty, omit_empty) : 
  Incorrect number of arguments (4), expecting 2 for 'C_stri_flatten'
  Calls: <Anonymous> ... stri_wrap -> sapply -> lapply -> FUN -> stri_flatten -> 
  .Call
```

I am using a structure that has the markdown call code from an external file. Early in the R Markdown code it is set up by the following code to the file:

````
```{r load file, echo=FALSE}
read_chunk('30to90Day.R')

```
````

I got this syntax from this link on [External R Code Blog](http://zevross.com/blog/2014/07/09/making-use-of-external-r-code-in-knitr-and-r-markdown/)

The code that it is executing when it throws the error is below:

````
```{r cleanCols, echo=F}
```
````

The `cleanCols` code below is in the file referenced above `read_chunk('30to90Day.R')` using the knitr syntax.

```
## @knitr cleanCols

# rename and clean up
# change the column names
colnames(data) <- c('ClmNbr',
                    'FeatureNbr',
                    'SnapshotDay',
                    'IncSnapshotDay',
                    'FinalPaid',
                    'AttyRepresent',
                    'BILimitPerson',
                    'InjuryType',
                    'ClmtAgeAtLoss')

# change ClmNbr to character
data$ClmNbr <- as.character(data$ClmNbr)

# count of na
datatable(data %>% group_by(SnapshotDay) %>%
            summarise(count = sum(is.na(IncSnapshotDay))))


# clean up attyrepresent
data$AttyRepresent <- as.character(data$AttyRepresent)
data$AttyRepresent <- as.factor(
  ifelse(is.na(data$AttyRepresent), 'Unk', data$AttyRepresent))

# get only the data with values at 30 and 90
dataClean <- data %>% filter (!is.na(IncSnapshotDay))
```

All of the above code works fine outside of R Markdown.  My system environment is below:

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server >= 2012 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] bindrcpp_0.2.2             plotly_4.8.0               PerformanceAnalytics_1.5.2
 [4] xts_0.11-0                 zoo_1.8-3                  scales_0.5.0              
 [7] ggplot2_3.0.0              knitr_1.20                 reshape2_1.4.3            
[10] DT_0.4                     markovchain_0.6.9.11       dplyr_0.7.6               
[13] RODBC_1.3-15               RevoUtils_10.0.7           RevoUtilsMath_10.0.1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_0.2.3   purrr_0.2.4        lattice_0.20-35    colorspace_1.3-2  
 [5] expm_0.999-2       viridisLite_0.3.0  htmltools_0.3.6    stats4_3.4.3      
 [9] yaml_2.1.16        rlang_0.2.1        later_0.7.3        pillar_1.3.0      
[13] glue_1.3.0         withr_2.1.2        bindr_0.1.1        plyr_1.8.4        
[17] stringr_1.3.1      munsell_0.5.0      gtable_0.2.0       htmlwidgets_1.2   
[21] evaluate_0.11      httpuv_1.4.5       crosstalk_1.0.0    parallel_3.4.3    
[25] Rcpp_0.12.18       xtable_1.8-2       matlab_1.0.2       promises_1.0.1    
[29] backports_1.1.2    jsonlite_1.5       RcppParallel_4.4.1 mime_0.5          
[33] digest_0.6.13      stringi_1.2.4      shiny_1.0.5        grid_3.4.3        
[37] rprojroot_1.3-2    quadprog_1.5-5     tools_3.4.3        magrittr_1.5      
[41] lazyeval_0.2.1     tibble_1.4.2       tidyr_0.7.2        crayon_1.3.4      
[45] pkgconfig_2.0.1    Matrix_1.2-14      data.table_1.11.4  assertthat_0.2.0  
[49] rmarkdown_1.10     httr_1.3.1         rstudioapi_0.7     R6_2.2.2          
[53] igraph_1.2.2       compiler_3.4.3
```

Is there a clash between knitr and rmarkdown?

Comment: What are you doing with `r load file`? If "load file" is the name of the chunk, I'm pretty sure it needs to be a single word, such as `load_file`.

Comment: `load file` as a chunk label is fine, although personally I do not recommend spaces in chunk labels. Anyway, you didn't provide a self-contained example (what is `data`?). We cannot run it, so it will be hard to diagnose. Your R version is a little old. As a blind shot in the dark, [I'd upgrade R and reinstall all packages first.](https://yihui.name/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/)

Comment: I would add `sessionInfo()` to the document, and make sure it matches what you see when running in R.  It's possible you're using a different library or package versions.